# Time for priority queues?

Tags: data-structures, computer-science

- How long it take for a priority list to build a list of n nodes? How does it accomplish this in said time?
- How long does the *delete-min* function (retrieve the smallest element and delete it from the list) take? How does it accomplish this in said time?

Comment: what's your implementation of the priority queue? sorted list? unsorted list? heap?

Answer (score 1):

depends on how you are building your priority queue. if you are using heap structure, it takes nlogn to build a priority queue. I remember a way building a min heap can be done in O(N) as well. look at CLRS for more info.

look at heap structure to find out how it does build the heap structure. essentially your comparator will be priority of the node.

delete-min takes O(logn). again look at heap data structure.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29

you can also use linked list for priority queue. with linked list, delete min would be constant as well. however build priority queue might go up to O(N^2) depending on your input.